# Handle exception in case a file cannot be read in the network because the network path is not accessible

Tags: dart

I am reading a file present on a network drive using `dart`. I want to return a blank list in case the file does not exist or the network cannot be accessed.
I have tried using try/catch and try/on blocks but I don't seem to be able to handle the exception.

##### Code

```dart
readJSONReport(String filePath) async {
  /// If file exists on shared network folder,
  /// read it and return the list. Else return blank list
  List<dynamic> jsonList = [];
  try {
    File file = await File(filePath);
    if (file.existsSync()) {
      jsonList = json.decode(await file.readAsString());
    }
  } on FileSystemException {
    print("File not found");
  }
  return jsonList;
}
```

##### Error Message

```sh
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '\\10.0.169.142\Users\Public\shared\reports\merged_report.json' (OS Error: The network path was not found.
, errno = 53)
#0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:356:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Another way to ask the same thing would be:
**How to check if a file exists on a network path using dart?**

Comment: Your code should be working fine . I tried running it locally and `file.existsSync()` returns `false` on my machine. The `catch` is correct too

Comment: thanks @fperson the exception was from a different part of the code. Added the updated code as an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70480310/7048915

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP Here. Turns out, the exception was being raised from a different part of the code. Adding the code I use now to read a JSON file while checking whether the file exists or not.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

readJSONReport(String filePath) async {
  /// read report file generated by JSON Reporter
  /// if file exists, read it and return the list
  /// if file does not exist, return empty list
  List<dynamic> jsonList = [];
  try {
    File file = await File(filePath);
    print("Reading $filePath");
    if (await file.exists()) {
      jsonList = json.decode(await file.readAsString());
    } else {
      print("File does not exist");
    }
  } catch (e, stacktrace) {
    print("Exception occured: $e stackTrace: $stacktrace");
  }
  return jsonList;
}
```

Please note that the JSON I am reading starts as a list (as you can expect from a cucumber-json report).